# Congrats! :) Ubuntu 15.04 boot failure after latest kernel update 3-19-0-31

Tags: boot, kernel, 15.04

Ubuntu 15.04 boot failure after latest kernel update 3-19-0-31

*Fixed with Recovery from 3-19-0-30.

Linux Ubuntu 15.04 alongside W10.

Boot failure (black screen, infinite loading) today after 3-19-0-31.

Grub > Recovery from 3-19-0-30.

Comment: You installed a testing kernel at your own risk.